How can I link Boost library against my project using Github Actions under Windows? [CMake]
I'm currently struggling with Gihub Actions and can't manage to build Boost tests under Windows machine using CMake.
CMake built the project without any issues, but it couldn't link against the Boost library.
Any suggestions how to improve the code?
Thanks
MyProject/
├── .github/workflows/
│   └── release.yml
├── include/
│   └── IPParser.h
├── src/
│   ├── IPParser.cpp
│   └── main.cpp
└── tests/
    └── test_IPParser.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(PATCH_VERSION "1" CACHE INTERNAL "Patch version")
set(PROJECT_VERSION 1.0.${PATCH_VERSION})

project(IPParser VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})

# Set C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
IF( WIN32 )
    # The auto-linking feature has problems with USE_STATIC_LIBS off, so we use
    # BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB to turn it off.
    # Several boost libraries headers aren't configured correctly if
    # USE_STATIC_LIBS is off, so we explicitly say they are dynamic with the
    # remaining definitions.
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB -DBOOST_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_IOSTREAMS_DYN_LINK -DBOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK)
ENDIF( )

# Include directories
include_directories(include)

# Add executable for the main program
add_executable(IPParser src/main.cpp src/IPParser.cpp)

# Find Boost library
find_package(Boost 1.65 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Add executable for the tests
add_executable(runTests tests/test_IPParser.cpp src/IPParser.cpp)

target_link_libraries(runTests ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

# CParck configuration
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "NSIS;ZIP")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "IPParser")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT example@example.com)
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-win64")

include(CPack)

enable_testing()

add_test(runTests runTests)

.github/workflows/release.yml
name: "C++ CI"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - feature/github_actions

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true

      - name: Set up CMake
        uses: jwlawson/actions-setup-cmake@v1.10

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          choco install -y cmake --installargs 'ADD_CMAKE_TO_PATH=System'
          choco install -y boost-msvc-14.2

      - name: Configure CMake
        run: cmake -S . -B build -DCPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION=${{ github.run_number }}

      - name: List build directory
        run: dir build

      - name: Build project
        run: cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD

      - name: Run tests
        run: ctest --test-dir build --output-on-failure

      - name: Package with CPack
        run: cmake --build build --target package

      - name: List build directory
        run: dir build

      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.run_number }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.run_number }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false

      - name: Upload Release Asset
        id: upload-release-asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: ./build/IPParser-1.0.${{ github.run_number }}-win64.exe
          asset_name: IPParser-1.0.${{ github.run_number }}-win64.exe
          asset_content_type: application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable

Github Actions output:
Run cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD
  cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
MSBuild version 17.9.8+b34f75857 for .NET Framework

  1>Checking Build System
  Building Custom Rule D:/a/02/02/CMakeLists.txt
  main.cpp
  IPParser.cpp
  Generating Code...
  IPParser.vcxproj -> D:\a\02\02\build\Debug\IPParser.exe
  Building Custom Rule D:/a/02/02/CMakeLists.txt
  test_IPParser.cpp
  IPParser.cpp
  Generating Code...
test_IPParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream::inst" (?inst@lazy_ostream@unit_test@boost@@0V123@A) [D:\a\02\02\build\runTests.vcxproj]
MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) [D:\a\02\02\build\runTests.vcxproj]
D:\a\02\02\build\Debug\runTests.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals [D:\a\02\02\build\runTests.vcxproj]
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I expect successful run of
cmake --build build --target ALL_BUILD 


What is content of Boost_LIBRARIES which you use in your code? You could print the variable's content e.g. with message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}").

Thank you for your reply.
Here is the output:
Boost_LIBRARIES: optimized;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2/boost_unit_test_framework-vc142-mt-x64-1_74.lib;debug;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2/boost_unit_test_framework-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_74.lib
